# custom env vars with rvmsudo

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I am trying to run a ruby script which needs root access for some of its tasks. I know that rvmsudo exists and I use it, but if I want to set up an env var such as `TEST_ENV=1`, it doesn't work.

Example:

```
rvmsudo ruby some_script_which_requires_root_access.rb
```

When I debug the script and examine the `ENV` hash, I don't see the `TEST_ENV=1` var. I have tried exporting the var via:

```
export TEST_ENV=1
```

and put this in `.rvmrc`, in `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` for the `current_user`, and also in `.profile` and `.bashrc` of the root user but doesn't work.

So my question is, where should I define or export this `TEST_ENV=1` so that when I run the script with `rvmsudo` it is part of the `ENV` ruby hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with:

```
sudo -E ruby some_script_which_requires_root_access.rb
```

it preserves your entire environment. so it should work as expected.

Comment: Note that the -E option documentation says "It is only available when
either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the setenv option is set in sudoers(5)."

Comment: Works if you setenv inside /etc/sudoers.

Comment: AFAIK is by default on macos, probably not under linux.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply editing the rvmsudo script and putting the envvar definition in there?

Comment: Yes, I did, I hacked it, that's the way I made it work. BUT it is ugly and I strive to provide elegance in my code and all my setups.